# Nuget, Source transformation and AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: package, nuget, transformation, assemblyinfo

I'm currently working on a NuGet package which need to configure a couple of things in AssemblyInfo.cs. I've added a AssemblyInfo.cs.pp file to my package in /content/Properties, however the transformation is not performed. Is this not possible?

Content of AssemblyInfo.cs.pp

```
using Client.Logging.Aspects;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;


[assembly: ProfileAspect(
   AttributeTargetTypes = "$id$*",
   AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method,
   AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public
 )]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not possible - http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/360970